# How to detect zoom scale of UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview, zooming

I want to increase height of `UIWebView` while user zoom in (like default mail app in iPhone).
So, I have tried the code below to find scrollview in webview and add `UIScrollViewDelegate` to use `scrollViewDidZoom` for detecting zoom scale to increase height of webview on this method.

```
// MessageAppDelegate.h
@interface MessageAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,UIWebViewDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate> {   
    UIWebView *webview;
    UIScrollView *scrollview;
}


//MessageAppDelegate.m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 320, 100)];
    webview.delegate = self;
    webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    webview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [webview loadHTMLString:@"<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=6.0 user-scalable=yes\">test test" baseURL:nil];

    [self.window addSubview:webview];

    // Find scrollview in webview
    for (UIView *view in webview.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            // Get UIScrollView object
            scrollview = (UIScrollView *) view;
            scrollview.delegate = self;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale{
    NSLog(@"scale %f",scale);
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidZoom %f",scrollview.zoomScale);
}
```

The problem is I cannot zoom in/out on the webview 
but `NSLog` on `scrollViewDisEndZooming` method showed

> scale 1.0

when I ended zooming
and `scrollViewDidZoom` method didn't show anything.
I want to detect zoom scale of webview for calculating its height on `scrollViewDidZoom`.

What I've done wrong?
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I have done well for your code up,do following modificaitons:

you just get the scrollview class point ,then can get the scrollview.contentSize.width,which can change when you zoom in out,but scrollview.zoomScale always remains 1.so have to use contensize.width to calculate scale.

```
@interface dictViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate>{

UIScrollView *scrollview;
......................

//scrollview.delegate = self;

for (UIView *view in webViewM.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        // Get UIScrollView object
        scrollview = (UIScrollView *) view;
        //scrollview.delegate = self;
    }
}
/*
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale{
//NSLog(@"scale zooming %f",scale);
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
//NSLog(@"scrollViewDidZoom %f",scrollview.zoomScale);
}*/


- (void)swipeRightAction:(id)ignored
{  

 NSLog(@"wid=%f", scrollview.contentSize.width);
 NSLog(@"zoomscale=%f", scrollview.zoomScale);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a proper way to do it from the exposed APIs, but there is a hacky way.

A `UIWebView` contains a `UIScrollView` which can be given a delegate. Then when zooming changes, you (the delegate) get a callback called [`scrollViewDidZoom:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidZoom%3a).

In order to find the scroll view, you can get the `subviews` collection from the web view and iterate to see which one `isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]`.

Now, `UIWebView` also conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`. So that may mean you are changing the web view's implementation, and that could be a Bad Idea. Test well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to implement same as default mail app in iPhone that user can zoom only message content and while zooming it look like the height of webview increasing. I've tried to use webview set on footer of UITableView. I zoom on webview but it show scroll bar of both tableview and webview. I think if I increase height of webview depend on zoom scale it will show scroll bar only on table view. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Has anyone been able to do this. I am trying to do the exact same thing mimicking the native mail client UI but not able to do so. How to reposition other views when the webView zooms?